# alasql & grouping functions: use Javascript or AlaSQL to create the resulting object?

Tags: javascript, alasql

Below the input data:

```
[
        {
            "name": "jim",
            "color": "blue",
            "age": "22"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sam",
            "color": "blue",
            "age": "33"
        },
        {
            "name": "eddie",
            "color": "green",
            "age": "77"
        }
]
```

I would like a resulting object using a single AlaSQL query:

```
{
        "jim": {
            "color": "blue",
            "age": "22"
        },
        "sam": {
            "color": "blue",
            "age": "33"
        },
        "eddie": {
            "color": "green",
            "age": "77"
        }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve it one shot with a AlaSQL query ?
This would allow to easily find contact info (e.g. data["eddie"].age)

The closest way I found is this:

```
var res = alasql('SELECT name, ARRAY(_) AS details FROM ? GROUP BY name', [data]);
```

but I still obtain an array under this format:

```
[
    {
        "name": "jim",
        "details": [{
            "color": "blue",
            "age": "22"
        }],
    },
    {
        "name": "Sam",
        "details": [{
            "color": "blue",
            "age": "33"
        }],
    },
    {
        "name": "eddie",
        "details": [{
            "color": "green",
            "age": "77"
        }]
    }
]
```

What would be the fatest and efficient way to achieve the goal ?